# At what time did Q reach his destination given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A person P started from town X at 10 am and went towards town Y. Another person Q started from Y at 12 pm and went towards X. They met at 2 pm. P reached his destination 20 minutes after Q did. At what time did Q reach his destination?

MyApproach:

Let Z be the point where P and Q met. Let x be the elapsed time for Q to travel from Z to X, so the elapsed time for P to travel from Z to Y is x+1/3.

@Edit

I am confused here. 4.Sx/Sx=2 . Sy/Sy and I also did after this 4/x=2/1+1/3x but I am getting no where to the result.

Sx and Sy are the speed Of x and y.

> Can Anyone guide me how to form the equation after this?Please correct me if i am wrong till here.

Comment: You need to also use the first equation.  If $d_1$ is the distance $XZ$ and $d_2$ is the distance $ZY$, then person $P$ took 4 hours to get to the meeting point, while $Q$ took 2 hours.  This way you can relate the ratio of distances to the ratio of speeds.

Comment: @Maciek Edited the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the time you are looking for by $t$, the speeds by $v_p,v_q$ and the whole distance by $R$.

Then you got the following equations:

1. $R=2v_q+4v_p$.
2. $v_p(t+2 \frac{1}{3})=v_qt=R$.

From here it is easy to get to quadric equation in $t$ and to get $t=4 \frac{2}{3}$.